# How to open a WMP file?

Tags: windows, images, windows-media-player, file-extension

I have some old photos in WMP files. I have tried the suggestions from here: http://fileinfo.com/extension/wmp But none of them worked. Is there any way to open them at Windows 8.1?

EDIT: I have files like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7bi411addidf6n/RADNAI%20DUBICS%C3%81NY.wmp?dl=0

Comment: Did you try renaming it to `.hdp`, as suggested?

Comment: Or try to rename it to .jpg as the format is similar.

Comment: “Similar” is not “same”, so that won’t work. It’s a different format, after all.

Comment: I tried and it did not help.

Comment: [Did you try the file viewer as suggest in your link?](http://fileinfo.com/software/windows_file_viewer)

Comment: Upload a sample WMP image somewhere we can download it, maybe one of us can figure out how to view it.

Comment: I tried the File Viewer and it did not work for me. The file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7bi411addidf6n/RADNAI%20DUBICS%C3%81NY.wmp?dl=0 Thanks for your help!